# iOS 6 Xcode 4.5 Auto layout Trouble

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, autolayout

Hi i have been trying to arrange this over and over with no progress. I have been following a Core Data Book and its a little old and it doesn't explain the new Auto Layout features. I have two views one on top cover half the screen. The other on the bottom covering the other half of the screen. When I change the orientation it distorts the boxes and there is a white gap between the two views in landscape mode. I would like for the boxes to cover the screen the same way it does in portrait mode.

This code I am using is [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/81707637/Shapes.zip).

Please explain how exactly Auto Layout works and how it will work for my case. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i try your code and Solved .Set Width ,Height in autolayout and set leading and Trailing for Horizontal Spaces For both the views in constraints in nib file using Autolayout method(ios6).

Comment: Can you repost the code after you fixed it I still cant follow what your saying sorry. If you could zip it up and post it that would be ideal. Thanks in advance

Comment: I still don't follow you. Are you able to emale me the fixed zipped project?

Answer (score 0):

easy.

1. select both `UIViews` then `Pin > Vertical Spacing`
2. select both `UIViews` then `Pin > Height Equally`
3. Run, will show as same as before with error in `console`
4. Delete both `Vertical Space (502)...`
5. Run and you are done.

Try it yourself.

[image]